# Digital signals with delays

Tags: digital-logic

I would like to build up a hardware logic, that generates the following digital signals:

[image]

When A goes HIGH (start-up), the signals should look like in the first graph and when A goes LOW (stop), the signals should look like in the second graph.

I know this would be pretty easy to design on a microcontroller, but for certification reasons this should be done in digital hardware. To generate the digital logic would be easy, if there would not be the different delays for turn on and off. That is the reason I cannot come up with a solution at the moment. Do you think this is even possible to solve in digital without going too complex? If not, I probably need a uC and certify the firmware.

Comment: honestly, a microcontroller sounds like the easiest, and easiest to make reliable, solution to this.

Comment: Could easily be done using a couple of 555's or similar. Bus as mentioned, MCU will be far easier, cheaper, more accurate and more reliable than most simple hardware solutions.

Comment: Ok, thank you, so that is exactly what I tought. I will go with the MCU then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very straightforward to do with a small and cheap CPLD or one-chip FPGA, rather than an MCU.

This is very a simple circuit to implement in VHDL or Verilog, using free software tools and simulator. You have then got flexibility if your functional/timing requirements change in the future.

Check your certification requirements but an HDL design for a CPLD/FPGA typically does not require any of the approvals testing that software for an MCU does.

Comment: interesting point!

Comment: I agree with this answer. A microcontroller would be cheaper and easier (for most), but if that's not allowed then a FPGA will give you the most accurate and consistent results compared to any other hardware solution.

Comment: Thanks @bunker89320. Am saying though that if both were equal cost etc, it'd be the CPLD all day, not MCU. Easier development, simpler result. On this site, MCUs get pushed for dedicated jobs that they're not suited for but small (3x3mm if you want)£2 CPLDs are smack on for, yet I don't see that at all in my clients' industries. Subjective view, obviously, but a fairly wide one (commercial, military, avionic, medical, automotive, space). Though 'MCUs first, for anything' is so oft said here, its the enthusiast/hobbyist in them and few would succeed getting MCU into those designs in OPs firms.